# Rails 3: scope is not true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

How do I convert the following into something that works on sqlite and mysql? Note, `internal` is nullable.

```
  scope :external, where("internal is not true")
```

(In Rails 4, one can simply use:)

```
  scope :external, where.not(internal: true)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### ActiveRecord is smart enough for doing this, just do:

```
scope :external, where(internal: [false, nil])
```

That would be transformed in similar SQL (with table name and quetes probably):

- for PostgreSQL and SQLite `internal IN ('f') OR internal IS NULL`
- for MySQL `internal IN (0) OR internal IS NULL`

#### If need more control you can use Arel:

```
scope :external,
  where(arel_table[:internal].eq(false).or(arel_table[:internal].eq(nil)))
```

Which would be:

- for PostgreSQL and SQLite `internal = 'f' OR internal IS NULL`
- for MySQL `internal = 0 OR internal IS NULL`

#### Remember, if you need to check NULL values in SQL always use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` expressions.

Expresions `... <> NULL`, `... = NULL`, `... IN (NULL)` are evaluated as false for everything.

So, `NULL <> NULL` is false and `NUL = NULL` is false.

Answer (score 1):

Try scope :external, where('internal IN (?)', [false,nil])

Answer (score -1):

Try `scope :external, where(:internal => !true)`

Comment: `!true` will return `false` and it will return `internal = false` values only and not null values.